# Wrapping Selenium "Expected Conditions" Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create my own Selenium class with custom functions so that test scripting will become a bit more intuitive and more robust in some scenarios, for my taste at least. One of my current tasks is to wrap all Selenium expected conditions (described [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)) so that eventually I will have a single function that looks something like that:

```
def waitForElement(self, elementName, expectedCondition, searchBy)
```

Where:

`elementName` - the name of the element I am looking for. That could be id, name, xpath, css, etc...

`expectedCondition` - this is where the Selenium expected condition is set. So that can be: element_to_be_clickable, visibility_of_element_located, etc...

The above function internally implements the standard Selenium `WebDriverWait` as follows:

```
try:
    if expectedCondition == "element_to_be_clickable":
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, defaultWait).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((searchBy, elementName)))
    elif expectedCondition == "visibility_of_element_located":
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, defaultWait).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((searchBy, elementName)))
```

All is good but I have a bit of trouble with passing the `searchBy` as a parameter. To remind, `searchBy` can be one of the following:

```
By.ID
By.NAME
By.CLASS_NAME
...
```

When I call this wrapper function from the main code, I do it with the below line:

```
self.waitForElement("elementName", "element_to_be_clickable", "By.NAME", "test")
```

So all parameters are passed as strings which is fine for everything except of the `searchBy` part.

So my question is: **How can I pass the `By.X` part as a parameter** to my function?
Hopefully I was able to describe my situation well. If I wasn't I will be happy to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I was able to solve this problem after asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25756166/1119381) question. So in order to obtain the desired functionality, the above-mentioned method will look like this:

```
def waitForElement(self, elementName, expectedCondition, searchBy):
    try:
        if expectedCondition == "element_to_be_clickable":
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.defaultWait).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((getattr(By, searchBy), elementName)))
        elif expectedCondition == "visibility_of_element_located":
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.defaultWait).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((getattr(By, searchBy), elementName)))

        . . .
```

So it can be called like this:

```
self.waitForElement("elementName", "element_to_be_clickable", "NAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start like this:

**Create main findElement method, that accepts By instance:**

```
WebElement findElement(By by) {
        try {
            return driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            logException("ERROR: Could not find - '" + by + "' on page " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            throw e;
        }
```

**Then create wait method, that uses the findElement method:**

```
WebElement findElementAndWaitElementToPresent(By by, int timeoutInSeconds) {
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
            return findElement(by);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            logException("ERROR: Element is not present: " + by + " on page " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**And pass By instance to the findElementAndWaitElementToPresent method:**

```
findElementAndWaitElementToPresent(By.xpath("//your_xpath"), 10);
```

or

```
findElementAndWaitElementToPresent(By.name("name"), 10);
```

something like this is done in the framework i am working on/with

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer but I was asking for a solution in Python.

Comment: oh, sorry :) but Python also has Webelement module you can work with. I advised you a structure how it can be implemented

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is that you are converting "By" datatype to string.

Simple way would be to pass it without quotes like below:

self.waitForElement("elementName", "element_to_be_clickable", By.NAME, "test")

Only additional thing you need to do is to add import as below for By in python module from where you are calling above method:

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By