# Can I provide Python class method as a parameter?

Tags: python, class, oop

I would like to provide a method of a class as a parameter. Below is a simple example of what I'm after.

Say I have some class defined like this:

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.str1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now I want to add a new method to this class that will perform some operation on that list. This operation will be provided as a parameter to this method. So for example it might look something like that:

```
def testMethod(self, arg1):
    print self.str1.arg1(1)
```

Where `arg1` is a list class method.

The idea is being able to call that method in the below manner:

```
TC = TestClass()
TC.testMethod("index")
```

And expecting to get a result as I would get from:

```
print self.str1.index(1)
```

If I run it as is, I will get an `AttributeError` exception:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'arg1'
```

**NOTE**: This question was asked to generalize another issue, I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25743277/1119381).

Comment: I think you are looking for [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

Comment: It's rather confusing to have a list instance named `str1` (especially when you go on to refer to it in some places as a "string"). Please use sane variable names!

Comment: @Blckknght Changed the "string" to "list". Can't change the variable name however as it's already appearing in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print getattr(self.str1, arg1)(1)
```